# Changing the naming of a coordinate system in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, editing, utm, well-known-text

For compatibility reasons with a different software I need to change the naming of a CRS in QGIS (ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N). After georeferencing a file in QGIS I would like the CRS to show up in the file like this:

Original:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",...

Required:
PROJCRS["**ETRS.UTM-32N**",
BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",...

Is there a way to make this possible in QGIS?

I've tried changing the "description" of the CRS in the srs.db but that didn't help.

EDIT
The WKT used in the attempt to create a custom CRS:

```
PROJCRS["ETRS.UTM-32N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        ENSEMBLE["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble",
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1989"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1990"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1991"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1992"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1993"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1994"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1996"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1997"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2000"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2005"],
            MEMBER["European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2014"],
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[0.1]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Europe between 6°E and 12°E: Austria; Belgium; Denmark - onshore and offshore; Germany - onshore and offshore; Norway including - onshore and offshore; Spain - offshore."],
        BBOX[38.76,6,84.33,12]],
    ID["EPSG",25832]]
```

Comment: Proj and GDAL and QGIS are using the official names from the EPSG database. In your case https://epsg.org/crs/gml/id/25832. It may be possible to do what you want but I am not sure if it is a good idea. Maybe instead of editing an existing CRS you could add a new custom CRS.

Comment: I tried defining a CRS using the WKT format. When I copy the parameters from the existing CRS mentioned in my original question, and then edit only the line as shown above, the validation check says it's a valid definition.

When pressing OK it returns an error box that says (translated): Definition '' is invalid. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Please add the WKT into your question so other people can have a try as well.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the question.

Comment: I get a very clear error: `Cannot save 'test' - the definition is equivalent to EPSG:25832. Hint: Try removing ID["EPSG",25832] from the WKT definition.`